# Normal Bayes Classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, gaussian, naivebayes

plz help me. Im beginner in ML. How can I train normal Bayes classificator with different types of covariance matrix suggestion?
I have a task: to train normal Bayes classificator:

1. to evaluate covariance matrices of different classes if they are a) equal,diagonal b)differenr scalar ect
2. Calculate the classification points of trained Bayesian classifiers for a,b...
3. show classes area

I do in on python, but i cant understand how can i do more than just GaussianNB(). As I know this function do a model without checking any types of matrices. Pls help me.